# Как сделать так чтобы ячейка автоматически выбирала последние введенные данные с условием

Tags: google-sheets-api

Как сделать так чтобы ячейка автоматически выбирала последние введенные данные с условием,
то есть

должно быть так:
выбираю из выпадающего ячейка наименование а в следующем ячейке показывает цену которая была при поступлении в базу, а таких данных по одному наименованию бывают много а мне нужны последние внесенные